# Deploy azure functions across resource groups

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have looked at the Azure functions documentation but couldn't quit find answer to my question and hence I thought I asked the wider user community.

We have a single Azure subscription with multiple resource groups for our different environments, so one group for dev, one for test and one for prod.

We have developed multiple Azure functions in dev and would like to use CI/CD to deploy to test and prod.

However, doing this manually Azure complains that the name of the function app already exists which is weird because that would imply that the function app name must be unique to the subscription or globally across Azure? Does that mean you need to name your function apps func-dev, func-test etc? That seems very ugly.

How have you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function App, as any App Service application, has to have globally unique name:

- [Naming Conventions -> Compute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/naming-conventions#compute).

Indeed, it's typical to include your environment into the App name.

Function names have to be unique within a single Function App, but may repeat in different apps.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for documentation like that to explicitly mention this uniqueness.

Comment: Guess we are stuck with naming the apps with the environment suffix.

Answer (score 2):

azure function name has to be globally unique (not just in your subscription), because the name would be like:

functionName.azurewebsites.net

so you cannot have a function with name `functionName` if you already created one, because the dns name for that is occupied.

you can use subfunctions to work around that, so create a subfunction called dev, test, and prod inside the function and call those

Comment: Yes, but doesn't the main function app name need to be unique as well (the container for the functions)? What I mean is, we are deploying the function app container across resource groups and these have to be named function-app-dev/test/prod etc.

Comment: you can use one function app (thats how its called i think) can be used to host multiple functions. you can use routes to determine which function out of all the functions being hosted on the function app to call: https://myfunction.azurewebsites.net/dev or https://myfunction.azurewebsites.net/test

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but the function app itself needs to reside in a resource group. Isn't the idea of resource groups to separate apps from one environment to another? Even if we have myfunction/dev, that would mean that myfunction itself must reside in a generic resource group and not in a environment specific resource group?

Comment: yes, there are lots of globally unique resources in azure (storage,sql, webapps, etc). nothing you can do about it. also not sure why do you accept that answer because my answer came 40 minutes earlier and states the exact same thing

Comment: Although both your answers were similar I accepted it because it included the link to the documentation where I could look into this in more detail.

Comment: you didnt ask for it, i didnt provide it, but i explicitly explained why this happens and what you have to do

Comment: No I didn't explicitly ask for it, but I did mention in my question that I didn't find any good information regarding the naming convention and scope for azure functions, so providing a link that mentions this is helpful for me as it is an answer with a reference.